# Prove $\mathrm{span}(T ) = \mathrm{span}(T \cup \{ 0 \} ) $

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that

> $$\mathrm{span}(T) = \mathrm{span}(T \cup \{ 0 \} ) $$

#### Try:

Pick some $x \in \mathrm{span}(T)$, then can write $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i t_i $ where $t_i \in T$. Notice, we can write
$ x = \sum_i \alpha_i t_i + \alpha_{n+1} 0 $, then $x \in \mathrm{span}(T \cup \{ 0 \} $)

Isnt just the other direction the same argument>?

Comment: Your try is indeed correct! $span(T \cup \left\{ 0 \right\})$ is the span of all vectors from the set $T$ and the set $\left\{ 0 \right\}$, since the set $\left\{ 0 \right\}$ spans nothing, you get that: $span(T) = span(T \cup \left\{ 0 \right\})$

Comment: @BrunoReis: The set $\{0\}$ spans the subspace $\{0\}$, which is not "nothing".

Comment: @AlexM. Correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the other direction is identical!

Although, one could use a well known formula regarding sums of subspaces, that $\text{sp}(U\cup  W)=\text{sp}(U)+\text{sp}(W)$ when $W=\left \{ 0 \right \}$.